# Производительность алгоритмов std

Tags: c++, производительность

Потихоньку учусь использовать алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки C++. Самодокументирование кода - это хорошо, но решил проверить и производительность. Например, std::accumulate. Qt Creator, mingw, windows, QTest. В объекте создаём приватные поля:

```
QVector<float>  results_;
float           sum_;
static const size_t size_=65536;
float           arr_[size_];
```

В конструкторе пишем:

```
std::fill(arr_,arr_+size_,1.0);
```

Создаём три слота:

```
void Tester::benchmarkSimpleLoopOverArray()
{
    sum_=0;
    QBENCHMARK
    {
        for (size_t i=0;i<size_;++i)   {sum_+=arr_[i];}
    }
    results_<<sum_;
}

void Tester::benchmarkSmartLoopOverArray()
{
    sum_=0;
    float * pf=arr_;
    float * pf0=pf+size_;
    QBENCHMARK
    {
        for (;pf<pf0;++pf){sum_+=*pf;}
    }
    results_<<sum_;
}

void Tester::benchmarkAccumulateOverArray()
{
    sum_=0;
    QBENCHMARK
    {
        sum_=std::accumulate(arr_,arr_+size_,0.0);
    }
    results_<<sum_;
}
```

В results_ результаты заносим, чтобы компилятор не выбросил ненароком весь цикл, увидев, что его результат не используется. Результаты меня обескуражили:

```
RESULT : Tester::benchmarkSimpleLoopOverArray():
     0.061 msecs per iteration (total: 63, iterations: 1024)
PASS   : Tester::benchmarkSimpleLoopOverArray()
RESULT : Tester::benchmarkSmartLoopOverArray():
     0.0000046 msecs per iteration (total: 78, iterations: 16777216)
PASS   : Tester::benchmarkSmartLoopOverArray()
RESULT : Tester::benchmarkAccumulateOverArray():
     0.0532 msecs per iteration (total: 109, iterations: 2048)
PASS   : Tester::benchmarkAccumulateOverArray()
```

На арифметике указателей получаем выигрыш на 4 порядка! Ради такого я готов написать пару лишних строк кода и строчку комментария.

Соответственно, вопросы:

1. Можно ли как-то улучшить производительность алгоритмов, как мы это сделали с обычным циклом? Я пробовал генерить два таких же указателя для начала и конца массива, результат получается хуже - таким же, как у наивного цикла.
2. Может ли кто-нибудь проверить, сохранится ли такое соотношение результата под другими компиляторами/операционками?
3. Ну и самый главный вопрос. Как получился такой огромный выигрыш у "хитрого" цикла? Я не настолько хорошо знаю ассемблер, чтобы залезть в код и посмотреть отличия, но получается, что в наивном цикле и стандартных алгоритмах используется какая-то очень тяжёлая операция, которой нет во втором примере. Какая?

Upd: спасибо zenden2k, проблема действительно была в том, что указатели я выставлял до входа в цикл. В результате второй тест полноценно выполнялся только один раз, а потом на входе в for проверял условие

```
pf<pf0
```

, которое не выполнялось - отсюда бешеное количество итераций и, соответственно, малое время на итерацию.

Comment: А компилировали с какими параметрами? надеюсь c  О1/O2?

Comment: Т.е. вы точно производительность релиза тестируете? В отладочной версии основное время уходит на проверки итераторов (границ например, переполнения, и т.д.) и отладочную диагностику.

Comment: Добрый день! Пробовал -O3, -O2, -O1 - разницы никакой. Только что производительность обычного цикла и алгоритмов от запуска к запуску имеет разброс от 0.053 до 0.061.

Comment: Да, тестирую производительность в  release. В отладке первый и третий тесты выполняются за 0.18 ms, второй - так же, как и в release.

Comment: Вообще у меня подозрение, что во втором случае компилятор превратил код во что-то типа одной аппаратной команды "посчитай сумму отсюда досюда". Вот только такой команды я не знаю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде.

Вот это

```
float * pf=arr_;
float * pf0=pf+size_;
```

должно быть внутри QBENCHMARK а не снаружи.

Также тесты у вас не равнозначны, потому что используется общая переменная sum_, она   принимает разные значения в зависимости от кол-ва итераций.
Ее надо инициализировать внутри QBENCHMARK

```
 float sum_ = 0;
```

Тогда получите приблизительно одинаковые результаты

```
RESULT : TestClass::benchmarkSmartLoopOverArray():
     0.058 msecs per iteration (total: 60, iterations: 1024)
PASS   : TestClass::benchmarkSimpleLoopOverArray()
RESULT : TestClass::benchmarkSimpleLoopOverArray():
     0.059 msecs per iteration (total: 61, iterations: 1024)
PASS   : TestClass::benchmarkAccumulateOverArray()
RESULT : TestClass::benchmarkAccumulateOverArray():
     0.059 msecs per iteration (total: 61, iterations: 1024)
PASS   : TestClass::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 5 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of TestClass *********
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, ваш эксперимент выглядит неправильным. У вас разное количество итераций, почему? Например, для «выигрышного» случая у вас почему-то 0x1000000 итераций, а не 65536 = 0x10000. Проверьте, скорее всего причина больших расхождений в этом.

1. Вы занимаетесь ненужной микрооптимизацией. Дело в том, что расходы на управление циклом ничтожны в любом из случаев. Если в вашем цикле делается что-то нетривиальное, то эта операция по времени зарулит управление циклом. Если же в цикле делается какая-то быстрая мелочь, типа сложения, то он всё равно быстрый, и выигрыш в несколько наносекунд  Кроме того, хороший компилятор с включенной оптимизацией скомпилирует ваш код в одно и то же, т. к. смысл у кода одинаковый.
2. Можно, конечно. Операционка, думаю, тут не у дел, а вот разные компиляторы оптимизируют по-разному.
3. Скорее всего, это просто ошибка. Проверьте сложение на *одних и тех же* данных.

---

Да, существуют случаи, когда микрооптимизации нужны. Обычно квалификации даже хорошего программиста не хватает, чтобы определить, где узкое место в программе. Поэтому обычно не принято заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией (как завещал дедушка Кнут), а использовать профайлер. Когда вы точно знаете, где проблема, вы можете провести оптимизацию там. Таким образом, вы не испортите читаемость и поддерживаемость программы там, где это не принесёт никакого результата.

Comment: Добрый день! Сложение _проверяется на одних и тех же данных_ - массиве arr_. Количество итераций QBENCHMARK выбирает самостоятельно, в зависимости от того, сколько времени заняла одна итерация - чтобы более точно измерить время.

Comment: Оптимизироваться надо не преждевременно, а по результатом профилирования - это тоже понятно. Но для того, чтобы заменить найденное при профилировании узкое место более производительным вариантом, надо этот вариант знать. Вот я и экспериментирую.

Comment: Ну и, собственно, подозрение, что "это просто ошибка" у меня есть, и это одна из причин, по которым я задал вопрос. Но я проверял результат выводом в qDebug - там всё правильно.

Comment: @BMP: Попробуйте не доверять QBENCHMARK'у, а измерить время вручную. Например, как среднее из 65536 итераций. Судя по всему, QBENCHMARK всё портит, и в «быстром» случае вовсе нет никаких вычислений. Или вычисления происходят только один раз. Возможно, поэтому там такое количество итераций.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, это не Вы публикуете на хабре статьи на эту же тему - http://habrahabr.ru/post/260025/ и http://habrahabr.ru/post/260193/ ? там есть ответы на многие Ваши вопросы.

Comment: Нет, не я. Я натыкался на эту статью (кажется, и на другие), но нигде не видел отличия на 4 порядка. Собственно, именно такой большой разрыв и заставил меня задать вопрос.